# When will the upper regularization of a bounded function not defined?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, regularization, semicontinuity

Suppose $E$ is a compact metric space.

A function $f :E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is upper semicontinous if for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(-\infty, c)$ is open in $E.$

For any real-valued bounded function $f$ defined on $E$, we can define the upper regularization of $f$ as 
$$\hat{f} = \inf\{ g: g \text{ is upper semicontinuous on }E, g \geq f \}$$

In [Kechris and Louveau paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1990-318-01/S0002-9947-1990-0946424-3/S0002-9947-1990-0946424-3.pdf), they define a sequence of functions using upper regularization:

$f_1 = \hat{f}$. For sucessor ordinal $\xi,$ if $f_{\xi}$ is defined, then
$f_{\xi+1}=\widehat{\widehat{f_{\xi}-f}+f}.$ For limit ordinal $\xi,$ if $f_{\lambda}$ is defined for all $\lambda < \xi,$ then $f_{\xi} = \widehat{\sup_{\lambda < \xi} f_{\xi}}.$

In the same paper, the authors stated that the function $\hat{f}$ may not be defined.

Question: What is an example $f:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_{\xi}$ is not defined for some ordinal $\xi$?

EDIT: The authors prove the following proposition (page $220$, part of Proposition $2$ in the same paper:

If $f = u - v$ where $u,v$ are upper semicontinuous functions, then for all countable $\xi$, $f_{\xi}$  is defined.

When the authors prove the above proposition, they apply transfinite induction to prove that for all countable $\xi $, $u \geq f_{\xi}$. Hence, $f_{\xi}$ is defined.

From the proof above, I 'guess' that when $f_{\xi}$ is not defined, it should be the case that $f_{\xi}(x) = \infty$ for some $x \in E.$ However, I fail to construct such an example, even at $\xi=1.$

UPDATE: According to the author, there is a gap in the proof in section $3$, Lemma $3$, case $3$ (successor case). If someone can fill in the gap, I would feel appreciated.

Comment: Do you know examples where $\hat f$ is not defined?

Comment: For bounded function $f $, I do not know any.

Comment: You write, in the question, that the authors write that $\hat f$ might not be defined. Do they give examples or do they mean that it might not be defined for unbounded functions?

Comment: They do not give any example. They define the upper regularization for bounded function but yet, they say the upper regularization might not be defined.

Comment: "Question: When will the function $f_{\xi}$ not [be] defined ?" -- What kind of answer do you expect ? Do you want a classification of functions $f$ such that that $f_{\xi}$ isn't defined for some ordinal $\xi$ or do you want to see an explicit example of such a function $f$ ?

Comment: @ToddLeason: I am interested to see an example of a function $f$ such that $f_{\xi}$ is not defined for some $\xi$.

Comment: Taking $\xi = 1$ in the paper's Theorem 4 (ii) (in section 3) should give 
an example. However, the proof is based on Lemma 3 and I don't see how the inductive proof of Lemma 3 works for countable ordinals: It starts with $\xi = 0$. Thus, the case $\xi = 1 = 0 + 1$ should follow from Case 3 for $\xi = 0$. But Case 3 requires an strictly increasing sequence $\xi_n$ with $\sup \xi_n = \omega^\xi=\omega^0=1$ (hence the sequence ends with  $\xi_n = 1$) such that the induction hypothesis holds for all $\xi_n$. ...

Comment: ... But the induction hypothesis hasn't been proved for $\xi_n = 1$, since the induction starts with $\xi=0$. So, in my opinion, the induction is missing the case $\xi=1$. If I where you, I would write to the authors and ask about this issue. 
However, I don't know if they're still active.

Comment: @ToddLeason: Okay, I will try to email authors.

Comment: If they reply, please let us know what they say.

Comment: Reply from Professor Kechris: It has been a very long time since I have thought about this subject but taking a quick look again in the paper, it appears that indeed the case ξ=1 is missing. Thanks for pointing this out.